# PHP equivalent of ObservableCollection<t>/List<t>?

Tags: php, class

In C#, I can create a class `Monster`:

```
public class Monster
{
    public string name;
    public bool mean;

    public Monster(string monsterName, bool isMean){
            name = monsterName;
            mean = isMean;
    }
}
```

Then I can create an `observableCollection` or `List` that adds monsters in some way:

```
public class MonsterMash
{
    public static List<Monster> MonsterMashList(){
        var temp = new List<Monster>();
        temp.Add(new Monster("Frankenstein", true));
        temp.Add(new Monster("Mr.Hyde", true));
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way in PHP to create a similar construct while ensuring that only monsters are added? Currently, my implementation is as follows:

```
public class Monster 
{
    public $name;
    public $mean;

    function __construct($monsterName, $isMean) {
        $this->name = $monsterName;
        $this->mean = $isMean;
    }
}

public class MonsterMash
{
    public static MonsterMashList
    {
        $temp = = array();
        array_push(new Monster("Frankenstein", true));
        array_push(new Monster("Mr.Hyde", true));
        return $temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to look into extending classes: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was thinking along those lines, but was not sure exactly how to implement. Perhaps I could add a method like addMonster(Monster $monster) to my MonsterMash class that is called within MonsterMashList.

Comment: @JTerry yes! if you want to enforce that only a `Monster` can be added, then `addMonster(Monster $monster)` is a great way to do it.